# .htaccess Redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I set up an .htaccess file to redirect requests to another folder on another domain? I don't want the links to break, I just want them to go elsewhere. Say mysite.com/image.jpg would redirect to site2.com/images/image.jpg.

Comment: You should probably clarify the webserver you're using.  I'm assuming Apache but it might be IIS or something else.

Answer (score 5):

In .htaccess (in Apache at least):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.yahoo.com/blah/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Just as an additional hint: You need mod_rewrite installed on your server to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Now, what a big surprise, the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) has lots of [useful examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html), including what you are looking for. Yeah, it really sucks that Google is down so often.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect the request. If you want to redirect everything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://other.example.com/images%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And if you just want to redirect requests with a path that end in `.jpg`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.jpg$ http://other.example.com/images%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/